# A bash script that will compare the creation time of all files in a directory to a timestamp stored in a variable

Tags: linux, bash

Good day.

I'm trying to create a bash script that will compare all files in a directory to a specific timestamp. This timestamp is stored in a variable. If the file creation date varies from the timestamp by a few seconds, it will print the filename.

It seems like the best fit would be the find command. So far I've tried:

```
find /directory/*.txt -type -f -newer $TimestampVariable
(with $TimestampVariable="Wed May 11 13:53:20 EDT 2022")
```

as a jumping off point. But that isn't going to work because it isn't reading the timestamp in the variable, and it isn't comparing it to a range of times between $TimestampVariable and five seconds later.

Comment: Add an example for TimestampVariable to your question (no comment).

Comment: GNU's `find` command expects a filename for reference after the `-newer` option and not a timestamp. See `man find`.

Comment: I'm using bash scripting on Red Hat Linux.

Comment: `-newer` compares `mtime`, not "file creation date".  Most file systems don't even record the file creation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU and BSD `find` you can use the `-newerXY` predicate.

For example, if you search for all the files modified in between `Wed May 11 13:53:20 EDT 2022` and `Wed May 11 13:53:25 EDT 2022` then you could do:

```
find . -type f -newermt 'Wed May 11 13:53:19 EDT 2022' -not -newermt 'Wed May 11 13:53:26 EDT 2022'
```

---

Then, given a timestamp variable in the following format:

```
TimestampVariable="Wed May 11 13:53:20 EDT 2022"
```

Here's how you can generate the two dates needed for the `-newerXY` predicates (I chose to generate the dates in ISO-8601 format because it's well supported).

- on Linux:

```bash
min=$(date -d "$TimestampVariable -1sec" --iso-8601=second)
max=$(date -d "$TimestampVariable +6sec" --iso-8601=second)
```

- on macOS:

```bash
min=$(date -j -v'-1S' -f '%a %b %d %T %Z %Y' "$TimestampVariable" +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z)
max=$(date -j -v'+6S' -f '%a %b %d %T %Z %Y' "$TimestampVariable" +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z)
```

Now you can do:

```
find . -type f -newermt "$min" -not -newermt "$max"
```

Comment: Thank you! will the `-newerxy` predicate accept a variable as an argument, if the variable stores a timestamp?

Comment: Thanks so much. That did the trick! The only change I made was to reverse the locations of the $min and $max variables in the find command.